# IntersectionObserver blur element on unfocus

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I have been working on a project with an image grid for a friend of mine. The idea behind the website was that when the images in one row come into focus it pops out and the remaining go back into their original sizes.

After some research I found the IntersectionObserver API for JavaScript and the following example: http://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/YWqWXJ I modified the code to change the threshold to

```
let options = {
  threshold: [1.0]
};
```

but those are just personal modifications, the issue I had was when I scroll down to the next element that comes into focus using the visible class but the previous elements still stay in focus. I wasn't sure about the best way to go about doing this.

I found [examples](https://github.com/matuzo/IntersectionObserver-Examples/) and was able to notice the following code:

```
function updateStatus(visiblity) {
      console.log(visiblity);
      const status = document.querySelector('.status');
      status.textContent = visiblity;
      status.className = 'status status--' + visiblity;
    }
```

but this is only for the top bar in the [Simple Example](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/matuzo/IntersectionObserver-Examples/blob/master/simple.html) I needed some help figuring this out, please and thank you everyone!